# Finding eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix:

$$
       A= \begin{bmatrix}
       7 & -2 \\
        15 & -4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and I am asked to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 1,2$. Now I need to find the eigenvectors:

$$(A-\lambda I)\mathbf u=\mathbf 0$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
       5 & -2 \\
        15 & -6 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \mathbf u=\mathbf 0$$
I created the augmented matrix and row reduced to get:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
       5 & -2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

I set $u_2=s$ and $u_1=\frac{2}{5}s$, thus $$\mathbf u=s\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{5} \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

However the answers say that the vector is $(2,5)$. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: You didn't go wrong. They just multiplied by 5. Since you have a constant s that won't matter.

Comment: Every non-zero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. That’s why it’s a mistake to speak of *the* eigenvector of $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention at the end of your work that you set $u_2=s$ and $u_1=\frac{2}{5}s$. You could have just as easily set $u_2=5s$ and $u_1=2s$ and it would still have solved the equation, as setting $s$ constant with anything for which the equation $u_2=\frac{2}{5}u_1$ holds will give you a solution. So you didn't do anything wrong in your analysis, you just chose a different pair of numbers to satisfy the equation than did the answer, and you solved it in a more general sense (as a function of a constant $s$) than did the answer. Your result is correct and is essentially the same as the answer.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense thank you very much

Comment: @Patrick if this answer satisfies you, please accept it as the answer to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalue equation is
$$
\mathbf{A}u = \lambda u.
\tag{1}
$$
Matrices are the embodiment of linear systems. So if the eigenvalue is scaled by $\alpha \lambda$, the scaled eigenvector becomes $\alpha u$.

That is, $(1)$ implies
$$
\alpha \mathbf{A}u = \alpha \lambda u, \qquad \alpha \in \mathbb{C}.
$$